# How to test Jobs in playframework?

Tags: testing, playframework

I have:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class SomeClass {

 .. doJob() ...

}
```

How I can test it in my Unit Test that doJob() actually launched **when application started**?

Comment: it sounds to me like you are trying to test the playframework code...

Comment: Like mericano1 said, you should assume that Play will have launched the job. If your bootstrap job has any measurable side-effects, you could test those if you really wanted to.

Comment: yes. i guess i need check whether I missed to put @OnApplicationStart annotation or not for this class.

Comment: Hi Ses, bumped into your question accidentally! Was asking the same question. Great minds...

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that this is not a unit test, but an integration test.

You can test your Job, by simply calling it using the syntax `new MyJob().now();`, but as you are looking to test the @OnApplicationStart function, the you would be better off doing this as a Selenium test, and checking the data that you expect to be made available from the bootstrap job is present.